# Using raw_input with functions in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to execute a function certain number of times as specified by the user, for user-specified values. I have written the following code

```
queries = int(raw_input("The number of queries to run: "))

for i in range(0, queries):
    a, b = raw_input().split(" ")

    def count_substring(str):
        length = len(str) + 1
        found = []
        for i in xrange(0, length):
           for j in xrange(i+1, length):
               if str[i] == a and str[j-1] == b:
                    found.append(str[i:j])
        print len(found)



string = 'aacbb'
print count_substring(string)
```

The function gives the number of sub-strings that start and end with user specified characters.

For ex:
In the string "aacbb" the number of sub strings starting with a and ending with c are 2.

Queries indicates the number of inputs, ex for queries = 2 , there will be two inputs of the sub strings, i.e a & c or a & b

I want this code to return 2 values as answers, but it returns only 1.

Comment: why would you define your function inside a for loop? define it above the for loop, have it take a and b as args.

Comment: and then call it within the for loop.

Comment: I count one substring starting and ending with 'c' in 'aacbb'

Comment: 'aac' ,'ac' . That's 2.

Comment: The substring starts with 'a' and ends with 'c', that's 2 as mentioned above.